# Modeling accounts for different types of users in Django

Tags: django, django-models

Say that you have an application where different kind of users can sign: Firms, Lawyers, and Clients. A Firm has many lawyers; a lawyer has many clients. The views for a firm user are, of course, different from the views of a lawyer user; the two are different from the client user.

How would you model the three different users? I can think the following approach:

Three different models with a `ForeignKey` to `User`, each with their own fields, e.g.:

```
class Firm(models.Model):
 user = models.ForeignKey(User)
class Lawyer(models.Model):
 user = models.ForeignKey(User)
 specialty = models.CharField(max_length=100)
class Client(models.Model)
 user = modelsForeignKey(User)
```

Now you can create, for instance, consultations as a separate model using two `ForeignKeys`: to `Lawyer` and to `Client`; you can also add resources to a consultation (like documents, or stuff like that) by creating a model `Resource` with a `ForeignKey` to `Consultation`.

This approach makes it difficult to distinguish among users: how do you know whether a `user` is a `Firm`, for instance - you need to query the database several times or assign a `Profile` to the generic `User` object.

You could also add only a `Profile` to the `User` and include a `Role`, and then you channel the views and authentication based on `user.get_profile().role`.

How would you deal with this problem?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I would do what you suggest here:

> You could also add only a Profile to the User and include a Role, and then you channel the views and authentication based on user.get_profile().role.

Create a profile with a choice field for the role. Create some decorators like @lawyer_only that make sure that your views are only accessibly by Lawyer role users.

Comment: Yes, I think I'll have to go with this. Thanks! (Good idea about the decorators)

Answer (score 0):

You could also consider subclassing the User model (model inheritance):
http://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/topics/db/models/#model-inheritance

You will have to go with the option of multi-table inheritance http://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/topics/db/models/#multi-table-inheritance since the User class is not an abstract model.

Comment: This is just a syntax sugar for OneToOne relations. I don't see a benefit over explicit OneToOne.

Comment: @Mike: Not exactly. When I design OO-software, I prefer to think in terms of the object model as my primary concern (data storage comes later). Therefore if a lawyer is a user, I'd rather make this "is a" relationship explicit in my code, so that can use a lawyer instance wherever a user instance is expected. Incidentally, ORMs model inheritance and single composition in the same way (as a one-to-one relationship). That said, Django's model inheritance does have some quirks that make it not work exactly as object inheritance.